# Setting a new Environment Variable from Custom Activity in a Workflow

Tags: environment-variables, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

Is there a way to either create a new Environment Variable from within a WF 4.0 workflow or update an existing one if it already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a enviroment variable inside an code activity.

Comment: Thanks. The question is how do I set it? Do you have a code sample?
Edit: Your answer set me on the right path. I found the call. it is on the Environment class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Activities.Statements.InvokeMethod activity to call the System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable static method.

In the Parameters setting, you'll need to pass 2 'In' parameters.  The first will be the name of your environment variable, the 2nd will be the value.

[image]